# WordPress debug - call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've just updated my WordPress to a new version & I'm getting this error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'restrict_admin' not found or invalid function name in /home/burngeopk/public_html/members/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287

There is only 1 string that has restrict_admin in my theme's function.php. I am looking for guidance how to rephrase this string to make it work.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin', 1 );
function my_function_admin_bar($content) {
  return ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) ? $content : false;
}
```

Comment: Since the error is in wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php file which is a core file - I might suggest that you'll try to re-update the version. Trying to manually fixing this issue might have further consequences on your wp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the function `restrict_admin` does not exist anymore.

Try to add it back to your theme? Here its source code:

```
function restrict_admin() {
 
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) ) {
        wp_die( __( 'You are not allowed to access this part of the site' ) );
    }
}
```

Source:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/

Comment: Thanks Mikael, works as intended when placed in theme's functions.php